# Insert new object into objects tree. How?

Tags: php

I have just finished creating this beautiful php object tree. How would I go about inserting new objects using a loop into the items node array? Basically **how do I insert new anonymous item objects into the items array** in this object tree?

Take a look

```
<?php 

    $phpObjectTree = 

    (object)[
      'apiVersion' => '1.0',
      'data' => (object)[
        'requested' => '2020-01-01T23:59:59.001Z',
        'status' => 'OK',
        'estimate' => (object)[
          'id' => '1001',
          'type' => 'Commercial',
          'client' => (object)[
            'name' => 'ABC Construction, Inc.',
            'address1' => '123 Main St',
            'city' => 'Salt Lake City',
            'state' => 'UT',
            'postalCode' => '84101'
          ],
          'summary' => (object)[
            'generalRequirements' => (object)[
              'default' => 0
            ],
            'salesTax' => (object)[
              'material' => 4.85,
              'labor' => 4.85,
              'equipment' => 4.85
            ],
            'overheadProfit' => (object)[
              'material' => 10,
              'labor' => 10,
              'equipment' => 10
            ],
            'contingency' => (object)[
              'default' => 3
            ],
            'performanceBond' => (object)[
              'default' => 1.3
            ],
            'laborPlus' => (object)[
              'dailyRate' => 280,
              'crewCount' => 0,
              'dayCount' => 0
            ],
            'locationAdjustment' => (object)[
              'factor' => 90.1
            ],
          ]
        ],
        'items' => [
          (object)[
            'id' => '2001',
            'number' => '09 91 23.00 0000',
            'description' => 'Line Item 1',
            'quantity' => 0,
            'unit' => 'sf',
            'material' => (object)[
              'cost' => 0,
              'costEach' => 9.99
            ],
            'labor' => (object)[
              'cost' => 0,
              'costEach' => 9.99
            ],
            'equipment' => (object)[
              'cost' => 0,
              'costEach' => 9.99
            ],
            'lineTotal' => 0
          ],
          (object)[
            'id' => '2002',
            'number' => '09 91 23.00 0000',
            'description' => 'Line Item 2',
            'quantity' => 0,
            'unit' => 'sf',
            'material' => (object)[
              'cost' => 0,
              'costEach' => 9.99
            ],
            'labor' => (object)[
              'cost' => 0,
              'costEach' => 9.99
            ],
            'equipment' => (object)[
              'cost' => 0,
              'costEach' => 9.99
            ],
            'lineTotal' => 0
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ];
    // SET JSON HEADER...
    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');

    print_r(json_encode($phpObjectTree));

?>
```

Comment: It's an object, so just use object notation to add something to it e.g. `$phpObjectTree->testKey = "test";`

Comment: Does what you wrote adds or sets an existing value to something else?

Comment: That would add at the top level (ie with `apiversion`). To edit you could do something like this: `$phpObjectTree->data->items[0]->quantity = 10;` which would change the first item quantity from 0 to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way you'd modify any array in php:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

```
$phpObjectTree->data->items[] = (object)[
  'id' => '2003',
  'number' => '09 91 23.00 0000',
  'description' => 'Line Item 3',
  'quantity' => 0,
  'unit' => 'sf',
  'material' => (object)[
    'cost' => 0,
    'costEach' => 9.99
  ],
  'labor' => (object)[
    'cost' => 0,
    'costEach' => 9.99
  ],
  'equipment' => (object)[
    'cost' => 0,
    'costEach' => 9.99
  ],
  'lineTotal' => 0
];
```

Comment: Freaking outstanding. Thank you! I should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Say billy, if I am going to populate this object with data returned in a PDO MySQL result set, would `PDO::FETCH_INTO` be the most appropriate for this task? I ask because `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` returns JSON that has been flattened.

Comment: Sorry I'm not really that familiar with PDO fetch modes - but here's some good reading I found: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_INTO.  You should probably ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use stdClass to create new object and add properties.

```php
$obj = new \stdClass;
$obj->newProperty = 'value';
```